# Finding $P$ Such that $D=P^TH\overline P$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If $$H=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & i & 2+i \\ -i & 2 & 1-i \\ 2-i & 1+i & 2 \end{bmatrix}$$ is a hermitian matrix, Find a Non-Singular Matrix P such that $D=P^TH\overline P$

I tried using the concept of similarity of matrices. The condition will hold good if i find a real orthogonal matrix P. I tried finding the eigen values but they come in decimals. Doesn't look good to me.

Comment: $H$ being Hermitian, there ought to be a *unitary* matrix $P$ that works. But if the eigenvalues are irrational, then they are irrational, and you may just have to settle for decimal approximations.

Comment: @GerryMyerson ok, does the condition $D=P^TH\bar P$ also means that the unitary matrix obtained at the end will also be real ? so that $P^T=P^{-1}$ and $\bar P=P$ ? Am i thinking the right  way ?

Comment: Think about the Hermitian matrix $$\pmatrix{0&i\cr-i&0\cr}$$ Are the eigenvalues real? Are the eigenvectors real? Do you get a matrix $P$ with real entries?

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no condition specified on $D$, I assume it just should be diagonal. You can of course compute eigenvalues $\lambda_i$ and the corresponding eigenvectors $v_i$, $i=1,2,3$, and form the matrices
$$
D=\mathrm{diag}(\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3), \quad
V=[v_1,v_2,v_3]
$$
giving the relation $HV=DV$ leading to $H=VDV^*$ and the question is answered with $P=\bar{V}^*$.

You can also compute the $LDL^*$ factorization of $H$. In this case
$$
L=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 \\ -i & 1 & 0 \\ 2-i & -i & 1\end{bmatrix},
\quad
D=\mathrm{diag}(1,1,-4).
$$
Then you get $D=L^{-1}HL^{-*}$ and the question answered with $P=L^{-T}$.
The matrix $P$ is
$$
P=L^{-T}=\begin{bmatrix}1 & i & -3+i \\ 0 & 1 & i \\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}.
$$

Comment: What do $L^{-*}$ and $L^{-T}$ mean?

Comment: $L^{-\star}=(L^{\star})^{-1}=(L^{-1})^{\star}$, where $\star$ is either $^*$ (conjugate transpose) or $^T$ (transpose).

Comment: Thanks. Never saw that notation. It's standard?

Comment: I'm not sure if it is so widely used to call it standard. It is used though in some books to simplify the notation.